# Is it possible to change my Vector Strategy? Open Layers

Tags: openlayers, vector

I added a layer previously on my code, thats it's source scope.

```
const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    loader: ()=> { ... }
});
```

I'd like to know if there is any way to change it's strategy using OpenLayers functions, like getSource().setStrategy() (i couldn't find it).

I also tried to create a new source but with **ol.loadingstrategy.all** as a strategy and after this used setSource() into the layer, but didn't worked as expected.

OpenLayers updated my feature's **source** but kept the old one working as well(somewhere in the memory).

Using a new source made my request double, now it requests the entire layer and partially using BBOX, how can i get rid of the old one? I think changing the strategy may be better, but i can't figure out how.

Deleting the entire layer and recreating it, is something that i don't want to do!

Comment: Does the new source have a different loader (or does a shared loader check for infinity in the passed extent)?

Comment: No. It doesn't.
I run the same function to build the loader, but passing the specific strategy i want to.(It's used in a if)

Comment: In that case the loader should check for infinity in the extent and not set extent in the url if it is infinity